# Stray line breaks spoil source code on dump/restore

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

To be concise: dump/restore process makes my functions’ source code look ugly! God knows why, but something adds extra line breaks to my beautifully formatted source code in a way that makes me really mad (and makes it harder to read my code). Just a small illustration of what happens after I restore my database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tr_std()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$







begin







  /* Standard trigger function */







  if ( tg_when <> 'BEFORE' ) then







    raise exception 'This must be a "before"-trigger only: "%"', tg_name;







  end if;















  if ( tg_level <> 'ROW' ) then







    raise exception 'This must be a row-level trigger: "%"', tg_name;







  end if;















end;







$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION f_tr_std() OWNER TO postgres;
```

The header and the footer were generated by pgAdmin. The rest is my own code.

PG version: 9.0.1
OS : Windows XP

Contents of bat file I use for dump:

```
@echo off
set curr_dir=%CD%
pg_dump --blobs --format=c --compress=9 --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 -U postgres rc2_dev > "%curr_dir%\dump.bak"
pause
```

Contents of bat file for restore is irrelevant, I reckon, because inside the dump source is damaged already.

I have absolutely no idea what causes such a weird behavior!!! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Rather than use an image to illustrate, perhaps use a quote. I, for one, am behind a severe firewall which blocks many images. Also links go stale over time making your question less valuable in the future.

Comment: Well, I thought my firewall was the most severe of them all :) The source code is so badly spoiled that I decided to use an image :)

Comment: What versions of PostgreSQL, pg_dump, pg_restore/psql and pgAdmin do you use? And what parameters do you use for pg_dump? And did you check your dump to see how your function is stored in this dump?

Comment: Ok, that shouldn't be missing, indeed :) Added

Comment: --format=c gives you a compressed backup, not plain text. I used the same parameters for pg_dump on my 9.0.1 database on XP and had no problems at all: All line feeds and tabs in my source code are the same in the original as the restored backup (using pg_restore). Sorry, can't help you. :(

Comment: I'd wager it's the problem with the client which you have used to create the function (pgAdmin3 by your description). Please check how the function looks like in the DB (`\df+ <full_function_name>` in `psql`).

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was with using > to redirect the output. If I rather use -f to let pg_dump write straight to the file then I get nicely formatted output.

So your example will become:
pg_dump --blobs --host=localhost --port=5432 -U postgres -f "%curr_dir%\dump.bak" rc2_dev

Answer (score 1):

I am willing to bet that the problem is not with dump/restore but with end of line handling between PostgreSQL and other Windows programs.  Remember that Windows uses CRLF for EOL's which is two characters wide, while UNIX uses CR and Mac uses LF.  This wouldn't be the first time end of lines were inappropriately mangled elsewhere in the tool chain.

The first thing to do is check the source code in your database.  For the function above, this would be a good place to start:

```
SELECT pro_src FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'f_tr_std';
```

There are only two possibilities.  Either the EOL's are mangled there or they aren't.  If they are mangled check the rest of your toolchain.  If they are not, check every program you are using between dump and restore.